# xlwings - Get and set named ranges

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I am working on a new project with xlwings and I was wondering if and how it was possible to access and/or set the named ranges' names of a workbook.

I know we can access a named range with the `Range()` function, but is it possible to get a list of names for a specific workbook (say the caller) and create a named range from python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version currently under development (v0.4.0) will have a `Range.name` property which will allow you to get and set named ranges: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/210

Comment: Great! Any idea when the next version is coming up?

Comment: A few weeks? But you could in theory already install it from github directly: see https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git

Comment: This has been now been released with v0.4.0.